# You have reached maximum pool size for given partition

Tags: orientdb

can somebody please explain me what is the cause of this error:

> You have reached maximum pool size for given partition

Answer (score 1):

In latest 2.1.x version, you do not have this exception any more.
You merely wait till new connection will be available.

But I will explain it any way. To increase multiprocessor scalability pool is split on partitions and several threads work together on single partition.
Each partition has queue , when limit if connections for this queue is reached exception is thrown. But again it is already not the case for latest version.
So the best approach to fix this issue is to upgrade to latest version and set limit of maximum connections. Would be cool if you will add more information in your question , but I suppose that you use OrientGraphFactory which in latest version has maximum limit of connections equals to number of CPU cores.

Comment: yes i am using OrientGraphFactory , with a maximum pool size of 100

Comment: i am using orientdb 2.1.5 , still facing the issue. Do i have to upgrade to latest version ( 2.1.15 ) ??

Comment: Yes , you should upgrade to 2.1.15. But I suggest to wait till 2.1.16 (it will be released in couple of days) which will contain 2 critical hotfixes.